# Как создать горизонтальный разделитель

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как создать такой разделитель между текстом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
h1, p {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0.385em auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок тут какой-то</h1>
<p>И немного текста</p>
```